# Solving maximal area of rectangle under two functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

How do I solve the maximal area of rectangle under the functions $y=e^x$ and $y=5-x$ ?

I've tried everything and I'm out of luck, setting up expressions for the base and height hasn't worked and neither has changing the variable to $Y$ to flip the graph $90$ degrees. I'm new to this site, so I am sorry for any mistakes I am committing right now.

The rectangle is bound/limited by these two functions and the x-axis (which also is the base).

Comment: You should say that one of the horizontal sides of the rectangle is on the $x$ axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M(a,0)$, $Q(a,e^{a})$ and $N(b,0)$, $P(b,5-b)$ be the coordinates of the 4 looked for vertices.

The ordinates of points $P$ and $Q$ should be the same: $e^{a}=5-b$, thus $$\tag{1}b=5-e^{a}.$$

As the rectangle will have one of its sides equal to $MN=b-a=5-e^{a}-a$ (using $(1)$), the other one equal to $MQ=e^{a}$, the area is their product

$$A(a)=(5-e^{a}-a)e^{a}$$

And we have to find the value of $a$ that maximizes $A(a)$.

A necessary condition is that the derivative $A'(a)=0$.

What else have you to check ? Up to you...

Comment: Oh, that was rather standard... I'm completely embarrassed right now, I overlooked something that's rather standard. Thank you very much for helping me, I can't stress how much stress I've been under; which you just  relieved. Thank you very much!

Comment: It's very enjoyable to have people like you saying "thank you" !